# Untrusted Root when using dotnet restore

Tags: linux, .net-core

I am running Visual Studio Code and dotnet 5 on Mx Linux 19.3_x64 (Debian 10), when i try to run `dotnet restore` i get the following error:

> error : Unable to load the service index for source
> https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json. error :   The remote certificate
> is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: UntrustedRoot

Thinking that this could somehow be related to ca-certificates i tried to run `dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates` and `update-ca-certificates --fresh`, i also tried to install the unstable version of ca-certificates and reinstalling dotnetcore 5 but i wasn't able to solve this problem. Any help?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is related to [this issue with certificates on Debian-based distributions](https://github.com/NuGet/Announcements/issues/49). According to that link, Debian 10.8 should have resolved that issue.

Edited to add: [The Ubuntu ticket](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ca-certificates/+bug/1913951/comments/11) has the two certificates that need to be reenabled for this to work. I just followed these instructions, and mine now works.

Comment: I tried to use version 20200601~deb10u2 of ca-certificates, i reconfigured and made sure that certificates were checked but i still get the same problem. I also tried to use version 20210119 from the unstable repo but again no luck. Just to be sure i checked /etc/ca-certificates.conf and there are no deselected certificates.